# :host-context(selector) not working

Tags: angular

I have a requirement in such a way that there is a left-menu bar and click of any of the links `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` gets populated with particular component. With component getting populated, I want that particular link(`li` element in left-manu bar) to be highlighted with backgroud color.

So I'm trying this in child component:

```
:host-context(.account) li{
      background: red;
      color: red;
    }
```

But this is not working. Seems like the scope is only till `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` not beyond that in the parent component. How should I do?

Answer (score 0):

you would usually do this by applying a routerLinkActive="class" so e.g. in an anchor tag it would be

```
<a class="nav-link" (click)="onSelect()" routerLink='{{route.path}}' 
  routerLinkActive="active">{{route?.data?.name}}</a>
```

and in your css/scss you would style it like:

```
.active { background: salmon; }
```